# installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server on dell server R720

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I am having troubling with my installation of ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dell server.
my installation process goes on well, then the restart is initiated for me to boot into the system, but the system does not bootcompletely it enters into grub resuce mode after show that an attempt to read or write outside hd0.

Answer (score 0):

Use rescue mode to get into the rootshell, then in the rootshell use following commands :

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub

reboot
```